# How to use material icons in canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, google-material-icons

How to use material icons in canvas?

For fontawesome you can include the font and use the icon character code like:

```
ctx.font='30px FontAwesome';
ctx.fillText('\uF047',20,50);
```

But what about Google material icons? I couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: You can get Google material icons in an SVG format. Please take a look at [XMLSerializer​.serialize​ToString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString) and [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 4):

Provided you already have the font loaded  you can use it in a similar fashion as FontAwesome. Instead of the unicode string you just use the name of the icon.

```
context.font = '24px Material Icons';
ctx.fillText('calendar_today',20,50);
```

Comment: heads up that context.measureText won't report the correct width with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking, I found an answer here:

[How to render icon fonts on HTML canvas and Material Design icon fonts in particular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013793/how-to-render-icon-fonts-on-html-canvas-and-material-design-icon-fonts-in-partic)

In a nutshell: it uses a `FontFace` object to load the material icons. Then you use the `fillText` method from the canvas context to draw the icon.